# Start Azure Datafactory (v2) Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a ScheduleTrigger in Azure Datafactory.  I cannot change the runtimestate to started. I have tried using StartWithHttpMessageAsync. (and what feels like all the other start commands in the API)

the json for the trigger looks like this:

```
{

"properties": {

    "type": "ScheduleTrigger",

    "typeProperties": {

      "recurrence": {

        "frequency": "Day",

        "startTime": "2017-12-15T12:00:00Z",

        "endTime": "2099-12-31T00:00:00Z"

      }

    },

    "pipelines": [

      {

        "pipelineReference": {

          "referenceName": "DynamicFlowMaster",

          "name": "StartMasterPipeline",

          "type": "PipelineReference"

        },

        "parameters": {}

      }

    ]

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally answer...

While the documentation explicitly says:

"interval": <>, // optional, how often to fire (default to 1)

The Activity log in azure portal states:

'The template trigger is not valid: Required property 'interval' not found in JSON.

Adding the interval = 1 allowed the Client.Trigger.Start() - function to work, it previously only returned "Bad Request".